# Regex to extract substring, returning 2 results for some reason

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I need to do a lot of regex things in javascript but am having some issues with the syntax and I can't seem to find a definitive resource on this.. for some reason when I do:

```
var tesst = "afskfsd33j"
var test = tesst.match(/a(.*)j/);
alert (test)
```

it shows

```
"afskfsd33j, fskfsd33"
```

I'm not sure why its giving this output of original and the matched string, I am wondering how I can get it to just give the match (essentially extracting the part I want from the original string)

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Pay attention that you don't have the original and the matched string as you state. You have the matched string "afskfsd33j". Then the second item "fskfsd33" coming from the parenthesis in your regexp: (.*)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`match` returns an array.

The default string representation of an array in JavaScript is the elements of the array separated by commas. In this case the desired result is in the second element of the array:

```
var tesst = "afskfsd33j"
var test = tesst.match(/a(.*)j/);
alert (test[1]);
```

Comment: ohh ok, I guess I missed that.. thanks, i get confused with javascript sometimes since I'm used to the more restricted way of printing arrays in php

Comment: I probably sound dumb, but why does match return the original string? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @john-lee It's because the original string matches the regex `/a(.*)j/` and the second entry of the array contains the first matching group `(.*)`.
Furthermore the group(0) is always the whole match whereas group(n) is the n-th group marked by brackets. I hope this is understandable if not try [this documentation for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 10):

Each group defined by parenthesis () is captured during processing and each captured group content is pushed into result array in the same order as groups within pattern starts. See more on http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html (choose right language to see supported features)

```
var source = "afskfsd33j"
var result = source.match(/a(.*)j/);

result: ["afskfsd33j", "fskfsd33"]
```

The reason why you received this exact result is following:

First value in array is the first found string which confirms the entire pattern. So it should definitely start with "a" followed by any number of any characters and ends with first "j".

Second value in the array is captured group defined by parenthesis. In your case group contains string consist of any character with length <0; infinite). Which is entire source without starting "a" and ending "j" which are defined outside parenthesis, so exactly "fskfsd33".

If you want to get rid of second value in the array you may define pattern like this:

```
/a(?:.*)j/
```

where "?:" means that group of chars which match the content in parenthesis will not be part of the resulting array.

Other options might be in this simple case to write pattern without any group because it is not necessary to use group at all:

```
/a.*j/
```

If you want to just check whether source text matches the pattern and does not care about found texts then you may try:

```
var result = /a.*j/.test(source);
```

The result should return then only true|false values. For more info see http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re3.shtml

I would recommend test page https://regex101.com/ where you can test the patterns with full explanation how the RegExp works.

Answer (score 8):

Just get rid of the parenthesis and that will give you an array with one element and:

- Change this line

  `var test = tesst.match(/a(.*)j/);`
- To this

  `var test = tesst.match(/a.*j/);`

If you add parenthesis the match() function will find two match for you one for whole expression and one for the expression inside the parenthesis

- Also according to developer.mozilla.org docs :

> If you only want the first match found, you might want to use
> `RegExp.exec()` instead.

You can use the below code:

```
RegExp(/a.*j/).exec("afskfsd33j")
```

Comment: It's nice to add "g" param at the end of the regex, which stands for "global" and is used to specify that a regular expression should perform a global search.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that the match method is returning an array. The 0th item in the array is the original string, the 1st thru nth items correspond to the 1st through nth matched parenthesised items. Your "alert()" call is showing the entire array.

Comment: I can't tell whether this is incorrect or just badly worded.  The first element in the array (`test[0]`) is not the whole string, it's the portion of the string that was matched by the whole regex.  In this case they happen to be the same, but if the regex had been `/f(.*)j/`, the result would have been `fskfsd33j, skfsd33` (the initial `a` is not included in the match).

Answer (score 4):

I've just had the same problem.

You only get the text twice in your result if you include a match group (in brackets) and the 'g' (global) modifier.
The first item always is the first result, normally OK when using match(reg) on a short string, however when using a construct like:

```
while ((result = reg.exec(string)) !== null){
    console.log(result);
}
```

the results are a little different.

Try the following code:

```
var regEx = new RegExp('([0-9]+ (cat|fish))','g'), sampleString="1 cat and 2 fish";
var result = sample_string.match(regEx);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
// ["1 cat","2 fish"]

var reg = new RegExp('[0-9]+ (cat|fish)','g'), sampleString="1 cat and 2 fish";
while ((result = reg.exec(sampleString)) !== null) {
    console.dir(JSON.stringify(result))
};
// '["1 cat","cat"]'
// '["2 fish","fish"]'

var reg = new RegExp('([0-9]+ (cat|fish))','g'), sampleString="1 cat and 2 fish";
while ((result = reg.exec(sampleString)) !== null){
    console.dir(JSON.stringify(result))
};
// '["1 cat","1 cat","cat"]'
// '["2 fish","2 fish","fish"]'
```

(tested on recent V8 - Chrome, Node.js)

The best answer is currently a comment which I can't upvote, so credit to @Mic.