# How to write (A or B or C) followed by X in JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match a string on the format:

```
"XYZ 1234.10"
//XYZ can be one of a relatively large, but defined, set of 3 uppercase letter combination.
//String must start with XYZ or other from allowed set
//1234 can be an integer of arbitrary length >= 0
//10 can be an arbitrary integer in the range 0-99, but must have string-length of 2. (eg. 00, 03, 82)
//String must end with .NN (dot, number, number) /\.\d\d$/
```

I have tried the following regex, but captures "XYZ" as well as "XYZ 1234.10":

```
var regex = /^(XYZ|ABC|QST) \d+\.\d\d$/
regex.exec("XYZ 1234.10")
// => ["XYZ 1234.10", "XYZ"] would like it to be ["XYZ 1234.10"]
```

I would like to get a match only on the full expression. I have not been able to find a way to express this with javascript regex.

Is this achievable at all? If so: how can it be done?

Comment: `console.log(regex.exec("XYZ"))` results in *null*. Your regex looks more or less correct.

Comment: I'm confused - you _do_ get what you want in position zero. Do you just want to not capture anything else?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Nice one on the dupetarget. I wasn't expecting there to be a nice clear one like that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Improved my explanation. Also; thanks for pointing out what my actual problems consists of.

Comment: Question though: The "duplicated question" have an accepted answer which does not help in my case. Should it then really count as a duplicated question?

Comment: @Cort3z it is a duplicate. It explains exactly _why_ your "issue" is occuring. That should be enough knowledge for the matter. Not to mention that [one of the other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28232796/3689450) mentions non-capturing groups and it has nice informative references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>  // => ["XYZ 1234.10", "XYZ"] would like it to be ["XYZ 1234.10"]
> ```

`exec` is giving you the overall match followed by the contents of the capture groups. If you don't want the group to capture, make it a non-capturing group:

```js
var regex = /^(?:XYZ|ABC|QST) \d+\.\d\d$/;
// ------------^^
console.log(regex.exec("XYZ 1234.10"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing match and capture group. See output with a non capturing group:

```js
var regex = /^(?:XYZ|ABC|QST) \d+\.\d\d$/;
console.log(regex.exec("XYZ 1234.10"));
```