# javascript problems with .match and .substr not working together

Tags: javascript, match, substr

This is really puzzling me.

This works fine for me.

```js
var result = "this is my abc book";
console.log(result); // displays "this is my abc book"
var res = result.substr(3);
console.log(res); // displays "s is my abc book"
```

However, suppose I put "this is my abc book" into the field, and run this code, there are problems:

```js
var str = "this is my abc book"; //$(this).val();
console.log(str); // displays "this is my abc book"
var result = str.match(/abc.*/i);
console.log(result); // displays "abc book"
var res = result.substr(3);
console.log(res); // does not display at all!
```

It seems to me that .match is returning something which can't be cut by .substr.

I've also tried .split and .substring but not joy.

So in other words, how can I get a substr from a regex match?

Comment: [*match*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.match) returns an Array or *null*, not a string.

Comment: Please check your console when things does not work properly. There is a possibility of code breaking

Comment: Also use substring instead of substr since substr will confuse you too

Comment: Do you want to get substring from a first match or each match? Because match really returns an array

Comment: @mplungjan I purposely did not change that comment as OP is unaware about the error. Making it a part of question will mislead others

Comment: @Rajesh However when you made is a console.log, it was pretty obvious :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486359/regex-to-extract-substring-returning-2-results-for-some-reason

Answer (score 2):

[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return an array, hence you would need to use index to access the data within `result` (*i.e `result[0]` instead of `result`*).

Check below snippet.

```js
var str = "this is my abc book"; //$(this).val();
console.log(str); // displays "this is my abc book"
var result = str.match(/abc.*/i);
console.log(result); // displays "abc book"
var res = result[0].substr(3);
console.log(res); // does not display at all!
```

Comment: A comment should be more than enough and RobG's comment does it

Comment: A comment is not an answer (not here in stackexchange).

Comment: Hence the question can be flagged to be removed or marked as duplicate instead of answered

Comment: Excellent - thanks for that and the clear explanation!